# Get Logged in user's email id yahoo oauth php

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo

I have created an application which allows users to log in using their Yahoo credentials, I am able to retrieve some info like nick name and guid, but I am not able to retrieve email id of the logged in user.

I have given permission to Read contacts,mail,status apis to my yahoo application.

I am using Yahoo PHP SDK.

Can someone point what stuff am I missing here.

Comment: is it possible to share how you solve your problem. if is it possible it will be so helpful if you share your code too.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Activate `Social Directory -> Read Public` from http://developer.apps.yahoo.com in your project.

Then (in code):

```
$profile = $user->getProfile();
```

You will see the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Not having used Yahoo API, I can only speculate, but in general for popular service APIs (like Facebook, etc), email addresses are protected information. For FB, at least, you must be granted permission to view the email address, even if the user has granted you access to other areas of the profile.