# How to get YahooID of SessionedUser in social-sdk?

Tags: php, oauth, yql, yahoo-api

I have downloaded [Yahoo! Social SDK - PHP](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php) , got a key from developer.yahoo.com and made a web app that fetches user's contacts.

```
$session=YahooSession::requireSession(API_KEY, SHARED_SECRET);
```

My app can get all the user's contacts and their name,nickname,etc and their YahooID
what I need now is YahooID of user that accessed my app.

What I did :

```
$session->getSessionedUser()->getProfile()
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066030/get-logged-in-users-email-id-yahoo-oauth-php). but this gives me only user's GUID and nickname. I added `Social Directory -> Read Public` to list of permissions required for my app.

There are a lot of questions about how to get GUID from email/YahooID to get a user's GUID from YahooID O can use this query in YQL:

```
select * from yahoo.identity where yid='YahooID here'
```

But it doesn't works the other way (yahoo id from guid).